# Decorator pattern for an application

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, ruby-on-rails

I've created a decorator in my Rails application. However, the initializer has 3 params. Is this generally acceptable in decorator or should I refactor this or try a different pattern?

```
class FileBinderDecorator
  attr_reader :binder, :credential, :page

  def initialize(binder, credential, page = 1)
    @binder = binder
    @credential = credential
    @page = page
  end

  def file_items
    file_items = credential.file_item_list(excluded_ids: binder.file_items.pluck(:id))
    file_items.page(page).per(7)
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    @binder.send(method_name, *args, &block)
  end

  def missing_responds_to?(method_name, include_private = false)
    @binder.respond_to?(method_name, include_private) || super
  end
end
```

#### manage.html.slim

```
.modal.binder-modal.fade data-selected-ids=[] [id="edit-files-modal"]
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"
          span aria-hidden="true"  &times;
        h4.modal-title Edit Files
      .modal-body
        .container-fluid
          .row-fluid
            .credentials
              = select_tag 'credentials', options_from_collection_for_select(credentials_for_current_user_and_account(current_user, @account), :first, :last)
              .selectors
                .file-box-select-all
                  = link_to 'Select All', '#'
                .file-box-deselect-all
                  = link_to 'Deselect All', '#'
          .row-fluid
            .list-group[class="binder-#{decorator.id}"]
              = render partial: 'file_binders/filebox', locals: { file_items: decorator.file_items, binder: decorator.binder, credential: decorator.credential }
          .row-fluid
            .text-center
              .pagerx[class="pager-#{decorator.id}"]
                = render partial: 'file_binders/pager', locals: { file_items: decorator.file_items, binder: decorator.binder, credential: decorator.credential }
      .modal-footer
        button.add-selected.btn.btn-primary class="add-selected-#{decorator.id}" data-dismiss='modal' data-count=0 data-file-items=[]
          | Remove Selected
        button.btn.btn-cancel aria-label="Close" id="modalCloseButton#{decorator.id}" data-dismiss="modal" type="button" aria-hidden="true" Cancel
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea behind decorators, proxies and drapers is that they encase a single object. Yours seems to be serving two masters and has far too much knowledge of the different objects in your system.

It hard to get a picture of your models from the question - but it seems like you are missing a key relationship since you are passing `binder` and 
`credential` around together.

Also instead of creating your own proxying methods you can simply extend the [Delegator class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) but first you have to figure what you are actually proxying and stick to that object.

Comment: There is no direct relationship between binder and credential. I binders can have many files. And these files can belong to any credential that belong the same account as the binder.

Answer (score 1):

To expound on @papirtiger's answer re using the Delegator class, consider this meta programming...

```
class FileBinderDecorator
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  # ...    
  def missing_responds_to?(method_name, include_private = false)
  # ...
end
```

Can be reduced to this...

```
class FileBinderDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  def initialize(binder)
    super(binder)
  end
end
```

Then you don't need to pass the credential to the initialize method. But you can should you need to.

```
def file_items_for(credential)
  credential.file_item_list(excluded_ids: file_items.pluck(:id)).page(page).per(7)
end
```

Your view will be simplified too. Instead of calling `decorator.bind` you can treat the decorator as the binder object.

```
render partial: '...', locals: {
  file_items: decorator.file_items, binder: decorator ... }
```

I would take this a step further and pass in the view context.

```
  def initialize(binder, context)
    @context = context
    super(binder)
  end
```

And now you can initialize this from the view:

```
- binder = FileBinderDecorator.new(@binder, self)
```

Ideally you will want a nice helper for this. Now you can helpers from inside the decorators using the context.

```
= binder.render_file_box_partial

def render_file_box_partial
  @context.render partial: 'file_binders/filebox', ...
end
```

You might want to wrap context in a helper for brevity. The convention is `h`, for helper.

```
  def h
    @context
  end

  def some_tag
    h.content_tag ...
  end
```

As you can see, a lot can be done to spruce this up.